# set totalPageCount programmatically in Jquery Datatable(ver:1.10.6)

Tags: jquery, datatables

There is a datatable using "serverside pagination", the trouble is its total count set by 99,999,999 for some reason. here how it seems.

[image]

Actually there 30 records and only first 3 page has rows since Displaylength equals to 10, rest of them empty which generated DT because TotalRecords set to 99,999,999

So all I need to do edit this using javascript.
When I type `$('#myTable).DataTable().context[0]` in console there is some properties:

```
_iRecordsDisplay: 99999999
_iRecordsTotal: 99999999
json: aaData:(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}], iTotalDisplayRecords:99999999 ,iTotalRecords:99999999,sEcho:"25"
```

so I tried these but not work;

```
asd.context[0].iRecordsDisplay=30
asd.context[0]._iRecordsTotal=30
$('#myTable').DataTable().page.len(10).draw();
```

how I tell dt there is 30 records actually so create 3 pages only?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the example given for server side processing, you can take a look at the JSON returned by the server code. https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

```
{
  "draw": 11,
  "recordsTotal": 57,
  "recordsFiltered": 57,
  "data": [
    [
      "Airi",
      "Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "28th Nov 08",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica",
      "Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "9th Oct 09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ],
//more rows here
}
```

To solve this you must make your server side code include the "recordsTotal" attribute in your response JSON.

Something like this in PHP:

```
$response = array(
    'recordsTotal' => count($data),
    'data' => $data,
);
echo json_encode($response);
```